# How to make transition of Headings in Landing Page

Tags: html, css

My HomePage has under navigation bar a 1024x500px slideshow going on.
I want headings over that slideshow.
The headings should contain some sentences, for example "Digital art".
I would like to make transitions for those headings and text.
They should change every few seconds, fly in and out, or fade in and out, not sure.
How can I make that?
Thank you all.
Here is a screenshot if the situation. http://pokit.org/get/?9e3304f02be8142576ed1a0fa568efc1.jpg 
Slider is not the problem. I want the headings to move over it.

This is the html section, the div that contains the slideshow, and I already put one h1

```
 <div class="heroImg" id="heroImg">
    <h1>
        Graphic Design and Digital Art
    </h1>
        <div id=slidercontainer>
            <div id=css3slider>
<img src="images/slideshowimg/malay.jpg" alt="White-tailed kite" >
<img src="images/slideshowimg/jkarta.jpg" alt="Hawk title=Hawk" >
<img src="images/slideshowimg/american.jpg" alt="Osprey" >
<img src="images/slideshowimg/aya.jpg" alt="Square-tailed kite" >
<img src="images/slideshowimg/malay.jpg" alt="White-tailed kite" >
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the css -

```
 #heroImg h1 {
  color: rgba(255,102,0,1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 250px;
  z-index: 99;
  font-family: "Exo 2", "sans-serif;";
  font-size: 2em;
  left: 170px;
  }



/*  Slider CSS */

@-webkit-keyframes slider {     
 0% { left: 0; opacity: 0; }     
2% { opacity: 1; }     
20% { left: 0; opacity: 1; }     
21% { opacity: 0; }     
24% { opacity: 0; }     
25% { left: -1024px; opacity: 1; }     
45% { left: -1024px; opacity: 1; }     
46% { opacity: 0; }     
48% { opacity: 0; }     
50% { left: -2048px; opacity: 1; }     70% { left: -2048px; opacity: 1; } 
72% { opacity: 0; }     
 74% { opacity: 0; }    
 75% { left: -3072px; opacity: 1; }     
 95% { left: -3072px; opacity: 1; }     
 97%  { left: -3072px; opacity: 0; }    
 100% { left: 0; opacity: 0; }
 }


@-moz-keyframes slider {     
0% { left: 0; opacity: 0; }     
2% { opacity: 1; }     
20% { left: 0; opacity: 1; }     
21% { opacity: 0; }     
24% { opacity: 0; }     
25% { left: -1024px; opacity: 1; }     
45% { left: -1024px; opacity: 1; }     
46% { opacity: 0; }     
48% { opacity: 0; }     
50% { left: -2048px; opacity: 1; } 70% { left: -2048px; opacity: 1; } 
72% { opacity: 0; }     
74% { opacity: 0; }    
75% { left: -3072px; opacity: 1; }      
95% { left: -3072px; opacity: 1; }      
97%  { left: -3072px; opacity: 0; }     
100% { left: 0; opacity: 0; }} 

 @-o-keyframes slider {     
 0% { left: 0; opacity: 0; }     
 2% { opacity: 1; }     
 20% { left: 0; opacity: 1; }     
 21% { opacity: 0; }     
 24% { opacity: 0; }     
 25% { left: -1024px; opacity: 1; }     
45% { left: -1024px; opacity: 1; }     
46% { opacity: 0; }     
48% { opacity: 0; }     
50% { left: -2048px; opacity: 1; } 
70% { left: -2048px; opacity: 1; }     72% { opacity: 0; }     
  74% { opacity: 0; }    
75% { left: -3072px; opacity: 1; }      
95% { left: -3072px; opacity: 1; }      
97%  { left: -3072px; opacity: 0; }     
100% { left: 0; opacity: 0; }} 

 @keyframes slider {     
0% { left: 0; opacity: 0; }     
2% { opacity: 1; }     
20% { left: 0; opacity: 1; }     
21% { opacity: 0; }     
24% { opacity: 0; }     
25% { left: -1024px; opacity: 1; }     
45% { left: -1024px; opacity: 1; }     
46% { opacity: 0; }     
48% { opacity: 0; }     
50% { left: -2048px; opacity: 1; } 
 70% { left: -2048px; opacity: 1; }     72% { opacity: 0; }     
74% { opacity: 0; }    
75% { left: -3072px; opacity: 1; }      
95% { left: -3072px; opacity: 1; }      
97%  { left: -3072px; opacity: 0; }     
100% { left: 0; opacity: 0; }} 



 div#slidercontainer { 
 position: relative; 
  overflow: hidden; 
 background: #000 
 }
 div#slidercontainer { 
width: 1024px;
 height: 500px; 
 }

 div#sidercontainer img { 
  width: 1024px;
  height: 500px; 
  float: left;
  }

  div#css3slider { 
  position: absolute; 
  width:5120px;  
 -webkit-animation-name:slider;
 -webkit-animation-duration:20s;
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
 -moz-animation-name:slider;
 -moz-animation-duration:20s;
 -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
 -moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-o-animation-name:slider;
 -o-animation-duration:20s;
 -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
 -o-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  animation-name:slider;
 animation-duration:20s;
 animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
 animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  }



  div#css3slider img { 
  float: right; 
   }

   div#slidercontainer:after { 

  font-size: 150px; 
   position: absolute; 
   z-index: 12; 
  color: rgba(255,255,255, 0); 
  left: 300px; top: 80px; 
  -webkit-transition: 1s all ease-in-out; 
  -ms-transition: 1s all ease-in-out; 
  -moz-transition: 1s all ease-in-out; 
  -o-transition: 1s all ease-in-out; 
  transition: 1s all ease-in-out; 
  }

  div#slidercontainer:hover:after { 
   color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.6);  
 }
```

Comment: Which slider are you using? Are you using any JavaScript libraries? What have you tried so far? Can we see some code?

Comment: Hey. It's pure css3. No Js.

Comment: I will post code, but I think it is large

Comment: the css is for the slider, but I don't think it's relevant

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 div#sidercontainer div.slidecontent { 
  width: 1024px;
  height: 500px; 
  float: left;
  }

div#css3slider div.slidecontent { 
  float: right; 
   }
```

Then add slide content div instead of image like

```
<div id=css3slider>
 <div class="slidecontent">
   <h1>Text to show</h1>
   <img src="images/slideshowimg/image1.jpg" alt="" >
 </div>
</div>
```